# How to find last mysql dump file in directory and inport it

Tags: mysql, shell, ubuntu, terminal, vagrant

I just found Vigrant, and I am trying to make a script that set up fully my development environment. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.01 like a server. With scrip now I install LAMP, set up a password for MySQL, and change the LAMP server public directory. Now I have a directory with many .sql dump file. I want to find the newest one and import it to my database. I have a problem with importing my last created .sql dump of database. I found a command that find last created file in directory.

`find /vagrant/VagrantFiles/DB/ -type f -exec stat -c "%n" {} + | sort -r | head -n1`

But when add mysql command to import it `mysql --user=root --password=pass < {}` and execute line like this:

`find /vagrant/VagrantFiles/DB/ -type f -exec stat -c "%n" {} + | sort -r | head -n1 | mysql --user=root --password=pass < {}`

I get the error in terminal `-bash: {}: No such file or directory`

How I can make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi after two days of searching the solution I found it.
I just separate this command in two part. Firs find newest file and remember it to variable, then execute mysql command with this variable. My inspiration for this solution is [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/323167/382066) post. And here it is the solution:

`last_dump=$(find /vagrant/VagrantFiles/DB/ -type f -exec stat -c "%n" {} + | sort -r | head -n1)
mysql --user=root --password=pass < $last_dump`